# seaborn scatterplot marker size for ALL markers

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, scatter-plot

I can't find out anywhere how to change the marker size on seaborn scatterplots. There is a `size` option listed in the [documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.scatterplot.html) but it is only for when you want variable size across points. I want the same size for all points but larger than the default!

I tried making a new column of integers in my dataframe and set that as the size, but it looks like the actual value doesn't matter, it changes the marker size on a relative basis, so in this case all the markers were still the same size as the default.

Here's some code:

```py
ax = sns.scatterplot(x="Data Set Description", y="R Squared", data=mean_df)
plt.show()
```

I just tried something and it worked, not sure if it's the best method though. I added `size=[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]` and `sizes=(500, 500)`. So essentially I'm setting all sizes to be the same, and the range of sizes to be only at 500.

Answer (score 190, accepted):

You can do so by giving a value to the `s` argument to change the marker size.

Example:

```
ax = sns.scatterplot(x="Data Set Description", y="R Squared", data=mean_df, s=10)
```

Comment: @Sören you can update legend with `ax.legend(prop={'size': 20})`, hope it helps

Answer (score 7):

About the update of the legend size, I got it by the attribute 'markerscale' from matplotlib.pyplot.legend

> markerscalefloat, default: rcParams["legend.markerscale"] (default: 1.0)
> The relative size of legend markers compared with the originally drawn ones.

```
plt.legend(markerscale=2)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to change the marker size for all plots, you can modify the marker size in `matplotlib.rcParams`. The markersize is under the key `'lines.markersize'`. This value is 6.0 by default and whatever is passed to it is equal to the square root of the value passed to `s=` in `plt.scatter`.

```py
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.rcParams['lines.markersize'] = 10              # <---- set markersize here

df = sns.load_dataset('tips')
sns.scatterplot(x='tip', y='total_bill', data=df);
```

---

You could also set the markersize after the plot by setting its size in the `ax.collections`. Scatter plot markers are stored in `Axes.collections`, which is a list of scatter plots in that Axes. It's possible to set a uniform marker size there using the `set_sizes()` method.

```py
# for a single scatter plot
ax = sns.scatterplot(x='tip', y='total_bill', data=df);
ax.collections[0].set_sizes([100])                 # <---- reset markersize here
```

[image: result]

```py
ax = sns.scatterplot(x='tip', y='total_bill', data=df, label='tip');
sns.scatterplot(x='size', y='total_bill', data=df, ax=ax, label='size');

# for multiple scatter plots, could use a loop
for scatters in ax.collections:
    scatters.set_sizes([100])
```