# Why the point size using sns.lmplot is different when I used plt.scatter?

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, graph, seaborn, lmplot

I want to do a scatterplot according x and y variables, and the points size depend of a numeric variable and the color of every point depend of a categorical variable.

First, I was trying this with plt.scatter:

Graph 1
[image]

After, I tried this using lmplot but the point size is different in relation to the first graph.
I think the two graphs should be equals. Why not?
The point size is different in every graph.

Graph 2
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [seaborn scatterplot marker size for ALL markers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52785101/seaborn-scatterplot-marker-size-for-all-markers)

Comment: Please do not provide data/code/error messages as images. Post the text directly here on SO.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is no so much descriptive but i guess you want to control the size of the marker. Here is more [documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.scatterplot.html)

Here is the start point for you.
A numeric variable can also be assigned to `size` to apply a semantic mapping to the areas of the points:

```py
import seaborn as sns

tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
sns.scatterplot(data=tips, x="total_bill", y="tip", hue="size", size="size")
```

[image]

For seaborn `scatterplot`:

```
df = sns.load_dataset("anscombe")
sp = sns.scatterplot(x="x", y="y", hue="dataset", data=df)
```

[image]

And to change the size of the points you use the `s` parameter.

```
sp = sns.scatterplot(x="x", y="y", hue="dataset", data=df, s=100)
```

[image]